# How do I read just text in a text file in Python?

Tags: python, text

I have a text with some data I need to copy into another text file
How do I read the text and copy it into my new text file?

The text looks like this

```
 bruce
 bruce@yahoo.es
 ['sony', 1.89172]
 ['samsung', 6.0535]
```

I need to read only the text (without lists) and asign it to a variable to copy them onto a new text file

I've tried

```
with open("InformeFinal.txt") as f:
registros = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in f if x.startswith('[')]
```

In order to get only the lists inside the text file, but now I need just the text file.

Comment: What constitutes text? Alphanumeric characters?

Comment: If you want to copy a (text or other) file _verbatim_ (maybe you don't), you probably won't even have to read it into python.

Comment: You should take a look at the documentation before posting questions like this one, pelase check [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('fromfile.txt')
filec = file.read()
fileb = open('tofile.txt', 'w')
fileb.write(filec)
file.close()
fileb.close()
```

Hope this helped. =)

Comment: But according to his example, the file is not.

Comment: Examples are often representative of the size of the original file /s. Ick you're also shadowing `file`....